# How to encode string categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keras, scikit-learn

So I have a dataset that is essentially the list of `Windows API` calls that a single program makes. Each row belongs to one program. Successive cells of the same row are the API calls made by the same program. My issue is not being able to figure out how to `encode` this categorical data so that I can make a regression-based `ML` model out of it.

I tried using the `Pandas` method, `get_dummies()` but that just seems to mess things up as there is an exponential increase in the number of columns that seems to be generated.

**My dataset looks something like this -**

```
ROW [9822] GetStartupInfoA LockResource GetCommandLineA GetModuleFileNameA ShowWindow EnableWindow DestroyWindow    lstrcpyW GetThreadLocale lstrcmpiW GlobalAlloc
```

I also have the list of unique APIs if that helps.

My goal is essentially to build a model that analyses the API calls and predicts if the program making these calls is benign or not.

Comment: what are the column names? All of your entries need to have a common set of columns if you're to use `get_dummies()`

additionally, if your programs don't all make the same number of API calls, you will have rows with different amounts of columns, which also isn't allowed for `get_dummies()`.

Comment: There are a lot of factors that determine how you should model your data set when creating a ML model. I suggest you add what the goal of the model is so the community can better assist you.

Comment: Hey Josh! The dataset doesn't have any column names. All the programs make the same number of API calls (at least, I am ensuring this by limiting it). Do you suggest I add column names? I didn't do it because it did not make any sense.

Comment: Fair enough. That makes sense considering the API calls are nominal. How should I go about mapping the API calls to a numeric value (As I have about 2000 unique API calls)? And I'm sorry if I don't understand, but how is this going to help the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

**This is integer encoding:**

```py
api_dict = {
'call_1': 1,
'call_2': 2,
'call_3': 3,
...}

#grab the corresponding value from the dictionary
`api_dict.get({api_name_here})`
```

I'm not sure how your data structure is arranged but assuming it is a *list of lists*:

```
for row in sheet:
    for cell in row:
       cell = api_dict.get(value)
```

One hot encoding is similar except the values will be converted to binary:

```py
from keras.utils import to_categorical

data = ['cold', 'warm', 'hot'] # 3 possible values
encoded = to_categorical(data)
```

*returns* 
`[[1 0 0],[0 1 0],[0 0 1]]`

~2000 different values will be converted to an 11-digit binary number, that means that in order to represent all different API calls, the function converts each value, 11 different columns of either 1, or 0. This is done to keep the data as neutral as possible.

If you use the algorithm I provided above, you will end up with a 1-1 replacement, but the value in the cell will be anywhere from 1-2000. This could affect the output of your model.

Alternatives:

1. Reduce the amount of calls you want to allow the program to make, this will reduce the columns
2. Reconsider what data you want your model to consider when making a prediction. You can remove any unneeded data or use a different approach to reduce it.
3. Change the structure of your table, instead of logging all of the calls, you can log things like total runtime, # of API calls, or anything else you think might affect your output. It's up to you.

Comment: I can't do this for all 2000 API calls. Why cannot I just use a Label Encoder or One Hot encoding?

Comment: Have you tried using the Label Encoder? Please update your question to include this information. No matter how you look at it, if you want your model to distinguish between 2000 different API calls, you are going to to have many different columns for your result.

Comment: The answer I gave you and the label encoder will yield the same result. `LabelEncoder` is a simpler example. If you need help with using that function, then you should make a new question.

Comment: Why will there be more 2000 columns if I have 2000 API calls and I one-hot encode my data?